# Xamarin Forms - Listview Recycling and binding - Fire too often on Android

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.forms, recycle

I have a custom `ViewCell` with bindings.

The first time I say tap on a button the bound view model command is fired. Then I refresh the ListView. I tap again on the button. The command is called twice. I refresh, I tap, now the command is called three times. Etc.
This behavior only apply on android with `ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement`. Without it it works fine. And with it on iOS it woks fine as well.

I'm not asking for a workaround (I could either not use `ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement` or setup all my cell elements in `OnBindingContextChanged`) but for a reason (if any).

Comment: You should add some code from your custom ViewCell definition, it may shed some light on why the issue is occurring.

Comment: It's related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/39843873/1826096